# How to access each field's value in a class with reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic-programming, generics

I got a class which is created by XSD.exe by VS2010.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.269
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.0.30319.1.
// 

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class transfer
    {

        private string sourceGLNField;

        private string destinationGLNField;

        private string actionTypeField;

        private string shipToField;

        private string documentNumberField;

        private string documentDateField;

        private string noteField;

        private string versionField;

        private transferCarrier[] carrierField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string sourceGLN
        {
            get
            {
                return this.sourceGLNField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.sourceGLNField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string destinationGLN
        {
            get
            {
                return this.destinationGLNField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.destinationGLNField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string actionType
        {
            get
            {
                return this.actionTypeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.actionTypeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string shipTo
        {
            get
            {
                return this.shipToField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.shipToField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string documentNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return this.documentNumberField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.documentNumberField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string documentDate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.documentDateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.documentDateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string note
        {
            get
            {
                return this.noteField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.noteField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string version
        {
            get
            {
                return this.versionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.versionField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("carrier", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public transferCarrier[] carrier
        {
            get
            {
                return this.carrierField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.carrierField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class transferCarrier
    {

        private transferCarrierProductList[] productListField;

        private string carrierLabelField;

        private string containerTypeField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("productList", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public transferCarrierProductList[] productList
        {
            get
            {
                return this.productListField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.productListField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string carrierLabel
        {
            get
            {
                return this.carrierLabelField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.carrierLabelField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string containerType
        {
            get
            {
                return this.containerTypeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.containerTypeField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class transferCarrierProductList
    {

        private transferCarrierProductListSerialNumber[] serialNumberField;

        private string expirationDateField;

        private string lotNumberField;

        private string gTINField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("serialNumber", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true)]
        public transferCarrierProductListSerialNumber[] serialNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return this.serialNumberField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.serialNumberField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string expirationDate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.expirationDateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.expirationDateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string lotNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return this.lotNumberField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.lotNumberField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string GTIN
        {
            get
            {
                return this.gTINField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.gTINField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class transferCarrierProductListSerialNumber
    {

        private string valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class NewDataSet
    {

        private transfer[] itemsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("transfer")]
        public transfer[] Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Also I got a console application like that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Load xml file
            using (FileStream xmlStream = new FileStream("C:\\SaleReturn01.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                //Read xml file
                using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlStream))
                {
                    //Serialize xml with class which is created by XSD.exe in visual studio and set class with xmlfile
                    //In that case we don't need to xsd referenced validation
                    XmlSerializer serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(transfer));
                    transfer deserializedStudents = serializer1.Deserialize(xmlReader) as transfer;
                    showTransferClass(deserializedStudents);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void showTransferClass(transfer x)
        {
            try
            {
                FieldInfo[] myFields = typeof(transfer).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
                foreach (FieldInfo field in myFields)
                {
                    if (!field.FieldType.IsArray)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", field.Name, field.GetValue(x));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", field.Name, "");
                        foreach (transferCarrier y in x.carrier)
                        {
                            showTransferCarierClass(y);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception : {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }

        public static void showTransferCarierClass(transferCarrier x)
        {
            try
            {
                FieldInfo[] myFields = typeof(transferCarrier).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
                foreach (FieldInfo field in myFields)
                {
                    if (!field.FieldType.IsArray)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("  {0} : {1}", field.Name, field.GetValue(x));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("  {0} : {1}", field.Name, "");
                        foreach (transferCarrierProductList y in x.productList)
                        {
                            showTransferCarierProductListClass(y);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Exception : {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }

        public static void showTransferCarierProductListClass(transferCarrierProductList x)
        {
            try
            {
                FieldInfo[] myFields = typeof(transferCarrierProductList).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
                foreach (FieldInfo field in myFields)
                {
                    if (!field.FieldType.IsArray)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("    {0} : {1}", field.Name, field.GetValue(x));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("    {0} : {1}", field.Name, "");
                        foreach (transferCarrierProductListSerialNumber y in x.serialNumber)
                        {
                            showTransferCarierProductListSerialNumberClass(y);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("    Exception : {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }

        public static void showTransferCarierProductListSerialNumberClass(transferCarrierProductListSerialNumber x)
        {
            try
            {
                FieldInfo[] myFields = typeof(transferCarrierProductListSerialNumber).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
                foreach (FieldInfo field in myFields)
                {
                    if (!field.FieldType.IsArray)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("      {0} : {1}", field.Name, field.GetValue(x));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("      {0} : {1}", field.Name, "");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("      Exception : {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All in all, I can get the fields' name, but each time I tried the get value of fields an exception thrown like that.
Now I got the true code and works.(Thank you Jon Skeet)

Do you have any ideas to improve this code?

Comment: "I got a generic class" - I see no evidence of generics there...

Answer (score 1):

Well yes... you're calling:

```
temp = fld.GetValue(null);
```

From the docs for [`FieldInfo.GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx):

> If the field is static, obj is ignored. For non-static fields, obj should be an instance of a class that inherits or declares the field.

So, what *instance* of the type are you trying to show the fields for? Pass that in as the argument to `GetValue`. Without an instance, the concept of "the value of the field" doesn't make any sense. It's like saying "What's the value of `String.Length`?" without referring to a particular string.

(Also note that your code would be clearer if you followed .NET naming conventions, and also if you only declared variables at the point of first use, restricting their scope.)